# PHP Newsfeed with Reload

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, pusher

I'm have a PHP and MYSQL based newsfeed. To get new content, the user has to refresh the page. I'm working on a push system that would update the element with new posts without refreshing the whole page. How would I go about that?

Comment: If you haven't, you might take a look at http://socket.io/. Even if you opt not to use it, it's (open) source code might provide a good blueprint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a job for [Ajax!](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_intro.asp)

Also if you want to make the work really easy, use [jquery](http://jquery.com/).  The Syntax would look something like this:

```
$.ajax({
type: "post", url: "/SomeController/SomeAction",
success: function (data, text) {
    //....
},
error: function (request, status, error) {
    alert(request.responseText);
}
});
```

**EDIT**

to have the page update when a user clicks on a "show more content" link you can either use javascripts onclick function or use jquery's built in stuff.

Regular JS:

```
<somekindOfLinkOrButton onclick("moarStories();")/>

<script>
    function moarStories(){
        //ajax here
    };
</script>
```

Jquery way (much eaiser)

```
<script>
   $("#ElementId").click(function(){
         //ajax here
   });
```

Comment: Wait, you down voted my based on the tutorial link?  Dude, the answer is still valid and the link I gave just as so

Comment: Yes, it is valid but poor. Just a link isn't an answer. Take a look [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Comment: Also, this is the wrong answer. He wants know how to PUSH news, not how to refresh them like this. Pushing and polling is something different.

Comment: Well I'd like to do it like twitter. So the user clicks on a dialogue which says new stories are available(which I already have working via Pusher) and he when they click on it, it will load the new stories. I just don't know what route to take. Websockets or AJAX (both are new to me).

Comment: @Martin. True, but I suspect that OP doesn't know that. And the solution is valid and useful.

Comment: Well for your first point, he asked for ideas not a full code solution.  Second point, I concede.  Your right its not a true push

Comment: I reversed my downvote, but I do not agree with your answer. No matter what OP knows, he asked for pushing, not polling

Comment: @Martin. Part of being a good teacher is understanding that what the student says and what he means may be two different things.

Comment: @Blaze It doesn't matter, he wanted push, answerer should give him an answer about pushing AND suggest him better solution if possible

Comment: Let me just clarify. All I need is a way to get content from a MySQL database to an HTML element in a predefined fashion without refreshing a whole page. And the content must be different for each user. Push or polling. I don't see much of a difference.

Comment: Yup, ajax would do that.  Its basically going to send post requests (or get) to your server requesting new information at regular intervals, then display it on the page.  Since its all javascript, there would be no page reload

Comment: Okay. Thank you. Now how could I keep that content hidden until the user clicks that show new stories button?

Answer (score 0):

You just send a request to the server and server tries to keep the connection alive until you get new update. When you get new update from the database, you just push it to the client and close this connection