# AJAX Request Not Getting Any Info

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Here's my PHP file code:

```
<?php
require('config.inc'); //Init DB.

$current_user_id = $_GET['uid']; //Set User ID From AJAX GET.

mysql_query("USE social-network"); //Set MySQL DB.

$userFavs = "SELECT subscribee_id FROM subscribe WHERE subscriber_id = '" . $current_user_id . "'"; //Get people user is subscribed to.

$query="SELECT * FROM posts WHERE (post_owner_id IN ($userFavs) OR post_owner_id = '" . $current_user_id . "') ORDER BY id DESC"; //Select posts by user AND by people user is subscribed to.

$result=mysql_query($query); //Do the query.

$num=mysql_numrows($result); //Get number of rows in query.

$i=0; //Display selected posts.
while ($i < $num) {

$owner_id=mysql_result($result,$i,"post_owner_id");
$content=mysql_result($result,$i,"content");
$date=mysql_result($result,$i,"date");


$poi_query=mysql_query("SELECT firstname, lastname, profile_picture FROM `social-network`.`users` WHERE id = '" . $owner_id . "'") or die(mysql_error());
$post_firstname=mysql_result($poi_query, 0, "firstname");
$post_lastname=mysql_result($poi_query, 0, "lastname");
$post_profile_picture=mysql_result($poi_query, 0, "profile_picture");
?>

      <div class="post">
        <h1 class="post-title"><a href="profile.php?user=<?php echo $owner_id; ?>"><?php echo $post_firstname; ?> <?php echo $post_lastname; ?></a></h1>
        <p class="content"><?php echo $content; ?></p>
        <p class="details"><?php echo $date; ?></p>

      </div>

      <?php
$i++;
}
?>
```

Here's my JS AJAX request:

```
function loadPosts()
{
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET","PHP/news-feed.php?uid=<?=$current_user_id?>",true);
xmlhttp.send();
document.getElementById("posts").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
```

Nothing shows up under the posts section on my page. What am I doing wrong? And the PHP code is tested and it worked when I just directly included it in the posts page. 
What I'm trying to do: [PHP Newsfeed with Reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10439557/php-newsfeed-with-reload)

Comment: use a debugger to see what is going on, may be install firebug extension for firefox and see in its console to figure where the issue is, is it sending the ajax request, is the server failing or what

Answer (score 0):

Where is the element with id "posts"?, I only can see a div tag with post class

Answer (score 0):

One thing that is wrong with your ajax, is that it is assuming to be synchronous: You are expecting a result right after you send your request but instead you should attach an event handler on the `onreadystatechange` event.

If you don't have any experience with ajax, I would recommend using a library like [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to handle that for you.

Apart from that I don't see where you are calling your ajax function either.